# Error con Visual Studio Code y Git

Tags: git, vscode

A la hora de configurar git en mac agrego el comando `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` y no me marca error pero a la hora de comprobar que salió bien y ocupar el comando `-e` para que abra el editor me marca que el directorio no existe, saben como solucionar este problema?

Error completo:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found
    error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Es posible que se debe a que no tienes habilitado code para ejecutarse desde la línea de comandos:

- Abre la paleta de comandos en VSCode (shift + command + p) y busca Instalar comando code en el path.
- Cierra code y vuelve a intentarlo con git.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo intente y no se soluciono el problema, me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: Reiniciaste ?? probaste code --version y tambien code ....

Comment: Funcionó a la primera, muchas gracias, Óscar Novás

Comment: Tengo este mismo problema. Intente la solucion de Oscar con la esperanza de solucionarlo pero nada aun... Ya reinicie la computadora. y Probe git --version y me arroja que tengo la version 2.32.1 Apple. Pero cuando intento iniciar el git config --global -e me arroja este mismo error... hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.