# Error en git: Waiting for your editor to close the file

Tags: git, vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando Power Shield y GIT BASH para realizar pruebas, y al colocar los comandos:

```
- git config --global -e 

- o el comando git commit

- No se si con otros comandos también me dara el error, no lo he probado
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn “code: No such file or directory error: unable to start editor '“code'
```

A pedido de Hola Eltshift0, probe este comando:

```
git config --global -l
```

y como resultado da esto:

```
core.editor="C:\Users\Bangho GMX-15s\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --wait
core.editor=“code
core.editor=“code
core.editor=“code
core.editor=“code
core.editor=“code
core.editor=“code
core.editor=“code
user.name=Mi Nombre
user.email=Mi correo
```

---

Información Extra, al instalar git, puse la opción para que vsc sea el editor.
Estoy utilizando windows 10.

**Respuestas de otros Foros 01**: Encontré esta respuesta, pero cuando pongo lo que indica en vsc (code, o >code, no entendí muy bien) , no emergen las opciones en vsc, es como si no existiera eso en mi vsc.
**NUEVA INFORMACION: En algún foro leí que esas opciones ya no están disponibles en las nuevas versiones y que solo se pueden activar al momento de la instalación de vscode (Cuando instale... si tenia activada la opción que dice instalar en PATH, y también probé sin activar esa opción, de ninguna de las dos maneras se soluciono el error, probé la versión 1.77.3 que es la ultima y también la versión 1.64.0 pero el error persiste)**

[Error con Visual Studio Code y Git](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/518424/error-con-visual-studio-code-y-git)

**Respuestas de otros Foros 02**: No entiendo muy bien lo que hace, (sugerencia, usar el traductor)

https://e-penguiner.com/trouble-shooting-githint-waiting-for-your-editor-to-close-the-file-error-cannot-run-editor-no-such-file-or-directory/

**Respuestas de otros Foros 03**

https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/setting-vscode-as-default-git-editor/975

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145766/discussion-on-question-by-claudio-error-en-git-waiting-for-your-editor-to-close); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución:** Les comento que no estoy seguro si quedo bien bien, pero lo que hice fue borrar el archivo gitinit, ese archivo esta en la carpeta c/users/
Lo borran y luego vuelven a cargar los datos:

```
git config --global user.name "AQUI TU USUARIO"

git config --global user.email "AQUI TU EMAIL"
```

Y AHORA USAN EL COMANDO QUE ME RECOMENDO eftshift0,

```
git config --global core.editor code
```

y luego usan el comando que me daba problemas git config --global -e y ahora ya no da el error (git commit tampoco da error)